# Add SQL query rows to a new array using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

I am executing a sql query on a database which returns all the data.

**SQL Code**

```
 $sql_query3 = $DFS->prepare( "

        select
              *
        from
              TABLE_NAME
        where

              WHAT_I_WANT = '".$variable."'

    " );

    $sql_query3->execute();

    $result3 = $sql_query3->fetchall();

    print_r($result3);
```

**Result of print_r($result3)**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [REFERENCE] => GBBRF707321224
            [WEIGHT] => 199.00
            [VOLUME] => 0.398
        )
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [REFERENCE] => GBBRF707321222
            [WEIGHT] => 620.00
            [VOLUME] => 1.240
        )
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [REFERENCE] => GBBRF707321220
            [WEIGHT] => 2465.00
            [VOLUME] =>4.930
        )
)
```

**Result of print_r($new_array)**

```
Array
(
    [0] => GBBRF707321224
    [1] => 199.00
    [2] => 0.398
)
Array
(
    [0] => GBBRF707321222
    [1] => 620.00
    [2] => 1.240
)
Array
(
    [0] => GBBRF707321220
    [1] => 2465.00
    [2] => 4.930
)
```

I am then looping through $result3 and selecting the values that I want from them. After I have got all the information that I want, I want to add them into a new array. However, when I try to do that, it adds everything into one long array.

I then tried `$new_array = array();` and then `$new_array[] = $row3['One']`. This works but creates separate arrays each time it loops through.

I want to be able to keep the array that is being printed out, but how the $result3 array is formatted.

**This is what Im doing right now**

```
 $new_array = array();

        foreach( $result3 as $row3 ) {



            $new_array[]   = $row3[   'REFERENCE'              ];
            $new_array[]   = $row3[   'WEIGHT'                 ];
            $new_array[]   = $row3[   'VOLUME'                 ];



    }
```

There are 2 issues with the $new_array.

First issue is that the rows are added to the $new_array with keys as index. I want to be able to insert a string as the key.

The second thing is that, I want the array to look like the $result3 array.

**Like this**

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (

            )
     )
```

Any tips or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to create temporary array a result3 array loop. then insert all values of result3 array into temporary created array and then insert temporary array into new_array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are always creating new index for `new_array`. Try this:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach( $result3 as $row3 ) {

  $tmp_array = array();

  $tmp_array[]   = $row3[   'REFERENCE'              ];
  $tmp_array[]   = $row3[   'WEIGHT'                 ];
  $tmp_array[]   = $row3[   'VOLUME'                 ];
  $new_array[]   = $tmp_array;



}
```

Comment: It gives the error "Function name must be a string on line 147" which is  $new_array[] = $tmp_array();

Comment: Change `$new_array[] = $tmp_array();` to `$new_array[] = $tmp_array;`